# Manga where the MC attends a hunter tournament, is belittled by the other attendees due to his clothing, and goes toe to toe with the instructor

Tags: story-identification, manga

My brother read this manga a few months back but forgot the title and I've been trying to find it ever since.

So the MC attends a prestigious due to his connection with his grandfather. And he attends a hunter tournament and is belittled by the attendees due to his manner of clothing, which is casual, as opposed to the noble attire the majority wear.

There's a part in the manga where their strength is gauged and the MC surprises everyone as he is able to go toe to toe with the examiner/instructor. Another detail is the top 1 and 2 strongest begin bickering upon the entrance of the MC in said tournament and the MC tries to defuse the situation.

Comment: Regarding "So the MC attends a prestigious due to his connection with his grandfather.", did you mean to say a prestigious school? Also, was this manga in black & white or in colour?

Comment: Ah yes a prestigious school sorry, I must have missed placing it. And the manga I'm referring to is in black & white.

Comment: What sort of time period was the story set in? Medieval? Contemporary? Futuristic? Also, what was the nature of the tournament? Martial arts? Magic? Something else?

Comment: It contains martial arts, magic and it's contemporary. Someone already answered and the title of the Manga is “Inferior psychic underworld returnee” but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Inferior Psychic Underworld Returnee](https://allanime.site/manga/djSkLQjB3qohfbFmo/Makai_Kaeri_no_Rettou_Nouryokusha)*

> Doumori Hiroto is a mysterious boy from a lineage of ancient spiritualist who have been guarding the pathway to the underworld for a thousand years. But he was born with a defect caused by bloodline of magicians mixed into his ancestry. He possessed both spirit and magic power instead of either, yet he was able to use neither. For this reason, his grandpa took him to his friend, a chinese sage, to have Hiroto being taught the sage cultivation. He quickly mastered the sage path and was said equal to a hundred years cultivator. Somehow, thanks to his sage power he became able to wield his original spirit and magic power. However, during an incident where he had to unleash his full power, the recoil of that power caused his existence to be erased from everyone's memory.